# Implementing range() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For fun, I implemented a version of Python's `range` function in JavaScript. I found that underscore.js implements it as well, but with notable differences. I'm hoping others can comment on the differences. I assume that underscore's implementation is, if not more optimal, at least more idiomatic. And I'd like to build my intuition for the best way to do things in JavaScript.

My version:

```
var range = function () {
    var results = [];

    // Allow comparison to be variable
    var lessThan = function (a, b) {return (a < b); };
    var greaterThan = function (a, b) {return (a > b); };

    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        var start = 0;
        var stop = arguments[0];
        var step = 1;
        var comparisonTest = lessThan;
    } else {
        var start = arguments[0];
        var stop = arguments[1];
        var step = arguments[2] || 1;
        var comparisonTest = ((step > 0)? lessThan : greaterThan);
    };

    for (var i = start; comparisonTest(i, stop) ; i += step) {
        results.push(i);
    };

    return results;
};
```

And underscore's implementation:

```
_.range = function(start, stop, step) {
    if (arguments.length <= 1) {
      stop = start || 0;
      start = 0;
    }
    step = arguments[2] || 1;

    var length = Math.max(Math.ceil((stop - start) / step), 0);
    var idx = 0;
    var range = new Array(length);

    while(idx < length) {
      range[idx++] = start;
      start += step;
    }

    return range;
  };
```

I see that not specifying function parameters - which made it easier to deal with variable lengths of `arguments`, ended up being more verbose than the way underscore handles it. Is there any other reason to always specify parameters?

And how about the actual building up of the range - underscore declares an Array constructor with length. Is that necessary?

Any insight or comments is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see that not specifying function parameters - which made it easier to deal with variable lengths of `arguments`

But it didn't really make it easier to deal with variable length args, as underscore's code demonstrates. It's true, though, that it makes it a lot easier to write the function definition without worrying about whether you should write `function (start)`, `function (start, end)`, or `function (start, end, step)`- but that's about it.

But regardless of how you write it in code document it.

Since JS doesn't really care too much about what you put in the args list, docs are the what you have to rely on.

Anyway, you can basically put whatever you want in the args list. But I'd lean toward following underscore's example, and write out the full list of arguments. Worst case scenario is that someone skips the docs, looks at the args list, and sees 3 arguments. So he/she writes calls the function with *all* of those argument, even though 1 or 2 would have achieved the same thing. But that's just fine. But if you don't write anything in the args list and don't provide docs, whomever wants to use your code (e.g. you yourself in 2 months) suddenly has to play JavaScript interpreter and read the code itself to figure it out. While that shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds it's still an annoyance.

Alternatively, you can do something like

function (start /*, [stop, [end]] */)

to clue a developer in on what the function expects. But that's still not a substitute for just documenting it well. Because even if you *are* looking at the function's code itself and figuring it out, you have no idea what `arguments[1]` might be, because there's nothing to indicate there even is a 2nd argument. You have to work backwards to understand it. Underscore has named arguments, that, even if they're `undefined`, just make the code itself a lot more readable right off the bat.

> underscore declares an Array literal with length. Is that necessary?

Necessary? No. A good idea? Yes.

By declaring the length right away, you save the computer the trouble of keeping up with a growing array. When you declare the length, the computer can start allocating the necessary memory right away, whereas if you build it up, it may have to allocate more memory for each `push()`, and copy chunks of memory around and similar busywork.

Will you ever notice the difference? Depends on what you're doing, but I'd say wager that no, you won't ever notice. But it's a pretty simple optimization to make, so why not? Not that this is something you have to always do when building arrays (and sometimes you just *can't* know ahead of time how big the array will get), but for a low-level function like this with potentially heavy usage? Yeah, might as well. It's still very readable, so it's a win-win, really.

Next up: Variables. Just declare your variables in one place - with sensible default values, if possible. You declare the same 4 vars in two different places. While it doesn't matter much, it's just basic code cleanliness to not repeat yourself.

Next up: The loop. You loop basically does this:

- declare and initialize `i`
- call `comparisonTest` with a couple of arguments

  - compare those arguments
  - return boolean
- if returned value is false, exit the loop
- if returned value is true:

  - append `i` to the array
  - increment `i`  by `step`
- repeat

Whereas underscore's does this:

- compare `idx` and `length`
- if false, exit the loop
- if true:

  - insert `start` at index `idx`
  - increment `idx`
  - increment `start` by `step`
- repeat

Your way *seems* to save a variable (underscore has both `idx` and `start`), but it's a losing battle: underscore's way saves *an entire function call for every iteration of the loop*.

Calling that comparison function means duplicating 2 variables (the arguments) plus the whole rigamarole of setting up return address, switching to the function's context, setting up `caller` and `callee`, `arguments` and all the other stuff a JS runtime does when you shove something onto the stack. Then it does the same sort of thing again when calling `push`. Since `push` is a native function, the calling overhead is no doubt lower,  but there's still the aforementioned overhead of (potentially) having to reallocate memory for a bigger array and all that.

Oh, and the engine also has to create those comparison functions when you call `range()` (I'd wager this is also pretty well optimized, but worst case scenario is a lot of extra work on every call just to do a simple comparison)

It's naturally more efficient to just *not* do any of that, as in underscore's solution.

Now, let me just make it clear that you rarely need to care about all of this. Once you start micro-optimizing your code, it's a deep, deep rabbit hole to go down, and most of the time it really doesn't matter. You're just spinning your wheels. All of this stuff is worth being aware of, but don't go overboard. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" as the saying goes.

So in the end, there's nothing really terribly wrong with your code at all, and I'm sure it can serve you well without any changes (except maybe some documentation). But it's of course hard to improve upon a battle-tested, built-for-speed library like underscore.

Comment: Can't give enough upvotes for the "so why not" argument. Why would you ever skimp on an improvement that was just as easy as the other way?

Comment: This is particularly helpful. Thanks. I'd like to push back on the claim that u_score saves a func call each iteration - the `while` loop performs the (yes, native) same comparison function each iteration, right? The comparisonTest func surely isn't being _created_ each iteration. So, other than the initial declaration, how does my comparison function require more overhead? Surely the implementation of `while` performs all the addressing and stacking stuff my comparison does? Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: @Luke It's impossible to tell exactly what'll happen. Engine optimizations are sometimes near-miraculous, and your implementation may well be faster! Or maybe it is for certain range sizes, and not for others. Too many variables to know for sure. But at face value, a loop isn't a separate context; a function is. A loop doens't have arguments, a return address, stack frame, etc; a function does - and more. Does any of that it matter? Only if you run the code, and find that it does.

Comment: @Flambino, can you point me to some sort of JS spec or something that would describe how a JS loop has no context or any of the things you describe? I imagine that document would be enlightening on a lot of subjects. Also, FWIW to everyone, I went to JSPerf and tested three cases - single arg, multiple arg, and negative step - of my code and my code subbing the arr.push for a declared array and index assignment - the push version was faster! It seems that the while loop is the real win here.

Comment: @Luke Wow, color me intrigued. I would've imagined the `push` to be heavier. Kudos! JS-engines are magic. And by context I basically mean scope. E.g. a var declared inside a loop is declared in the same scope as the loop itself. There's no local/block scope for loops. I don't dare speak to how it's implemented, though, esp. after your jsperf results. [Here's the ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) though, if you want to check it out.

Comment: @Luke I should note that much of my answer is based on old experience, and modern engines (i.e. post-V8, which has already been many years) turn a lot of that on its head. Makes sense for underscore to use the older approaches though, as it aims to run well even on older engines.

Answer (score 2):

The reason underscore defines the length of the results array from the beginning is because constantly having to change the length of an `Array` (using `push`) is more costly than defining its length beforehand and simply updating its elements.

As for having the parameters defined, I think it helps understand what the function is expecting. Instead of blindly passing in arguments and hoping they're in the right place, we can see what order `_.range` is expecting its parameters to be in. Also, because they specified the parameters, they can actually slim down their if-statement to just an if. Your implementation needs the extra `else` block to assign the `start` and `stop` variables.

Some improvements (that don't make your code essentially identical to `_.range`):

- You can move the declarations of `step` outside the if-blocks:

  ```
  var step = arguments[2] || 1
  ```
- You can do the same for `comparsionTest` since its only dependent on the value of `step`